# Voting to close after someone answered

Tags: discussion, closing

I took 15 minutes to write an answer, nobody comments, asks for precision, instead they do vote to close because "it is unclear" ?

I don't understand this attitude. I believe my answer explains in every detail why the question is very interesting.

[Fourier transform of the multiplication of $f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$ and $g(x) = e^{2\pi ix^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2556096/fourier-transform-of-the-multiplication-of-f-in-l2-mathbb-r-and-gx-e/2556128)

I think this kind of problem happens almost everyday.

Comment: Closing as unclear is a form of asking for precision, one which carries more weight because it has immediate consequences. The description "Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking." carries all the information you would put in a comment asking for clarification anyway.

Comment: Answering unclear questions is risky business. Half the time you wind up writing something that the OP will reject for one reason or another. I know we are all inclined to come to the defense of questions we as individuals find "interesting," but objectively speaking there is nothing mysterious about what we're seeing here. Hopefully the OP edits and improves so that the question gets re-opened! Although the chances of that now might be diminished since they already might have an answer...

Comment: Well, to paraphrase something I heard recently "I don't understand this attitude that question closure means a question is dead."

Comment: To me? I can't say either way. I don't understand the question or the answer. You're right,  exceptional solutions are sometimes the savior for bad questions. But this is a relatively rare and difficult thing to do, and I don't think it has happened this time.

Comment: @reuns No it does not. The question itself needs to be well defined on it's own terms. The fact that the question **can be** specified does not mean that the question was itself specific.

Comment: Ironically, this post would be greatly improved by adding context and further information. In particular, it would be nice if you could edit the OP to indicate why you think this is a problem and to include further information that shows that you're familiar with the oft-discussed cultural norms surrounding closing on this site.

Comment: @StellaBiderman What is unclear in the question ? The FT transforms multiplication in convolution, everybody knows that.

Comment: @reuns I listed two things that I think should be included in this post in the comment that you're responding to...

Comment: I don't understand it. Do I have to rewrite the question when answering ? This is ridiculous.

Comment: @reuns I'm saying that your question **here on meta** would be improved by adding more context to the question that you're asking **here on meta**. In particular, it would be nice if you could edit the post that you made **here on meta** to indicate why you think that **the closing of the MSE question** is a problem and to include further information that shows that you're familiar with the oft-discussed cultural norms surrounding closing on MSE.

Comment: You asked a question that we are currently having a discussion in the comments section of. I think that that question - the one we are currently commenting on - is unclear, because you don't provide elaboration for why you think that the described behavior is a problem, and you show no engagement with the massive amount of discussion we've had on this topic before.

Comment: @reuns This is a question and answer site, not a math forum- and long discussions are not desired. This place is optimized for clear questions and answers, not for dialogue.

Comment: @reuns It is not clear if the OP understand anything you write. It is indeed not even clear if they know what is Fourier transform. Without any effort from the OP, it is hard to guess their background and where they get stuck.

Comment: I strongly oppose the closure of this question. As I've commented before about meta questions, **closing is not a super-dislike**. Every meta question is opinion-based.

Comment: @JohnMa Yes, I and we are always aware of that when answering, and it is subjective to judge if we have enough hints on the readers' level to write a relevant answer.

Comment: I'd also like to add that I really don't agree with the closure as unclear - it's a clearly stated question for someone who knows what a Fourier transform is (and it's a bit curious that only two of the five close-voters actually seem to have any expertise in real or Fourier analysis, at least based on answer history...). Voting to close as missing context seems far more appropriate.

Comment: @user296602 : I skipped the review when I saw that question. Yes, sometimes it sucks when someone doesn't seem to understand the question voted to closed. But on the other hand, I do not have a good solution to this. We need more users to review close votes.

Comment: This question was appropriately closed,because it is based on a matter of opinion, not facts, and approximates a rant only, @user296602.  And my close vote was not, in any way, a "super downvote."  It was based on the fact that claiming an "attitude" the asker projects onto users here, and the criteria of "interesting from their own perspective, invites users to weigh in on the proposed "attitude (highly undefined)," and or whether the question is interesting or not.  When an opinionated post is asked, with no objective support, then closure as "based on personal opinion" is indeed justified.

Comment: And note, @296602, that the reason given here, is not a matter of a like or dislike, (nor should votes be Face-book style "likes)).  I think your belief upvotes/downvotes, close votes, reopen votes, delete/undelete boils down to face-book  liking or disliking, reflects your own motivation, but don't project that onto users in general.

Comment: @amWhy Fine, reword super-dislike to super-disagree. I see far too many worthwhile meta questions get closed (even though I might strongly disagree with the premise or suggestions they make) because many people do view closure as a valid way to express disagreement. Regardless of what you think my motivation is, there *are* a lot of people here that use votes as like/dislike buttons.

Comment: Bottom line, @user296602, The mistake in the situation the asker here rants about, is the very same user who chose to answer a very poor question.  The responsibility for what the asker rants about here, is themself.

Comment: @reuns, just because some people X, doesn't mean every one X's, nor that X-ing is justified.  Monkey see monkey do?  Perhaps that's how you or others operate, but don't overgeneralize what you see and what you do as  what any reasonable user would do.

Comment: Since the closure of this question is now being discussed, I want to say that I voted for “unclear/requires more info” for the reasons I outlined in the comments and not for opinion based.

Comment: @StellaBiderman Would you mind explaining why you voted to close this question *after answering it*? Either a question is worth answering or it isn't.

Comment: @user296602 I don't think that voting to close and thinking a question is fundamentally not worth answering are the same thing, especially on meta. In large part my answer is a compendium of my comments, with links and some elaboration.

Comment: One effect of closing the question is to stop others from providing answers. So your action seems questionable to me.  @StellaBiderman

Comment: @JohnMa Honestly I hadn’t thought this through particularly carefully. That makes sense, and I’ll refrain from doing this in the future.

Comment: @user296602 I agree with the stance against closure on meta in many cases. However, for the specific case I do think a case can  be made for closure. Not only is there no question (this can be alright on meta) there is not even a *clear* subject for discussion or concern. Plus the general subject came up frequently already.

Comment: Since I don't feel there has been much constructive discussion relating to the question posed here which doesn't even exist, and that everything that has been constructive has already been said elsewhere, I'm voting to delete this question.

Comment: I would respectfully submit that closure should be based on *the question* and the question that you refer to is really not a very good one. The OP put really no effort into it. In addition, the closure of an answered question is really not that big a deal. Folks can still vote on it, as I've just upvoted your answer. I've voted to close questions that I myself have answered, [like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2472557/). Ultimately, I think it's a mistake to put to much effort to answer a low effort question for exactly the reasons that rschweib states.

Comment: Having said that, I don't think this particular meta thread should be closed and deletion would be unreasonable. This meta thread implies a clear question, "why would one vote to close a question with a good answer?", and I don't quite see it as a rant, though I do think it should be written more clearly *as a question*, rather than as a complaint.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Indeed, if meta isn't the place where people like me/us (spending at least one hour per day on MSE) can complain (ie. explain the problems they encounter), not sure what it is useful for.

Comment: There is a big difference between "unclear what you're asking" and "I have zero knowledge on this topic and I have no idea what this question is talking about". Anyone who has seriously learned Fourier analysis knows that Fourier transform in $L^2$ is a relatively advanced topic and it is very clear what the linked question means, regardless the quality of the post *per se*.

Comment: As for the "zero effort" judgement: OP says in the question that $fg\in L^2$. It is an important step since not every function has a Fourier transform; this step justifies that $fg$ does have a Fourier transform so that one can make sense of the question.

Comment: I am the OP of this question and I think it was not really ill-posed. However, I edited it so that hopefully everybody can understand it. Actually, reuns exactly answered the question.

Answer (score 8):

Just because a question can be contextualized in an answer doesn't mean that the original question had the proper context. Answers have no bearing on the content of a question, and it is not a defense of the question in the context of discussion it's closure. Closure votes are a judgement of the question, not the question together with its answers. Many highly up-voted questions with excellent answers have been closed, for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/can-i-use-my-powers-for-good), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323334/what-was-the-first-bit-of-mathematics-that-made-you-realize-that-math-is-beautif), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220875/has-lack-of-mathematical-rigour-killed-anybody-before). It's excellent that you were able to give an answer that makes the question look good, but that doesn't matter at all to the question of if the question should be closed.

Furthermore, this question was not closed for the crime of "not being interesting." It was closed for being unclear. The close notification reads "Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need." One reason that this is appropriate is that the OP has shown no work or indication that they have thought about the problem. See [this meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23169/can-we-stop-the-show-your-work-craze) about showing effort and [this meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) about the definition of context for details on the community's policy.

Comment: Sorry for editiing my question so late. It's because lately I haven't been looking into my emails frequently.

Answer (score 4):

As one of five users who cast a close vote for the question, I *didn't* have an attitude when I hit the "Close" button.  I made this vote based on the quality of the *question* itself.  The answers appearing in grey color at the bottom were not supposed to be taken into consideration during the review.

Answer (score 1):

As one of the reviewers who closed the **question**, your answer looks well written and correct, but you are wasting your effort on such a low quality question.

In my opinion, the question writer is trolling for attention - save your math for better quality questions.

Comment: I agree with putting the question on hold, but (-1) for your extremely off-putting last line. Don't ascribe bad intentions to the asker when there is no evidence for it.

Comment: @user296602  I'm quite sure JonMark has a valid point; so lets use a different adjecitve: The question writer is..." a [help-vampire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire)  and it's a valid observation on virtually every site on the SE network.

Comment: @amWhy Describing someone as a help-vampire is one thing, although there's absolutely no evidence for it in this case - the asker has a long history of good answers, and a 8-1 ratio of answers to questions. But to accuse a well-intentioned poster of "trolling for attention" is ridiculous and more than a bit insulting.

Comment: @user296602 I object to the term "trolling" used in this case, too, and it is insulting.

Comment: Another comment, for JonMark: Why did you vote to close this question [62 seconds after answering it](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/4110)? Either it's worth answering or it's not. Pick one.

Comment: this meta question isn't that unique, most get closed, however this one seems to have generated quite a debate, (mind you that's an answer to me voting to reopen it aswell). I answered it because I voted to close the main site question, and so I felt I should.

Comment: The question can remain, with all it's debate, even without reopening.  I think you're inconsistent in what you claim (crappy question should not be answered), and your answering of a crappy question here on this meta post, and just like the asker of this meta post, you're arguing for the reopening of a non-question/non-quality question.  ??

Comment: The only thing I can say about this "answer" accusing me to be a math troll (or whatever you might want to call it) is: ridiculous. And yes, I take it as an insult. Thanks for the flowers.